# CSS positioning (IE and General!)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, css-position

I am having two problems with the markup for my website, and was wondering if anybody could help.

https://jsfiddle.net/d6nxx17y/ (a fiddle with the relevant code!)

```
<div id="container">

        <div id="titlebar">             
            <div id="titlebar_icon"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="menubar">
            <div id="menubar_user"></div>
            <a onclick="loadFaq()"></a>
            <a onclick="loadAbout()"></a>
            <span class="school_logout_button"></span>
        </div>

        <div id="central">
            <div id="centre_left"></div>
            <div id="centre_central"></div>
            <div id="centre_right"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">

            stuff here      

            <span style="float: right;">
                Stuff here too.
            </span>         

        </div>

        <div id="achievements_panel"></div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS

```
/* Position classes */
#body { }
#container { width: 75%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: -10px; }
#titlebar { position: relative; height: 100px; }
#menubar { position: relative; }
#central { position: relative; height: 500px; }
#footer { position: relative; clear: both; height: 50px; }
#centre_left { position: absolute; width: 250px; left: 0px; height: 100%; overflow: auto; }
#centre_central { position: absolute; left: 250px; right: 250px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: auto; }
#centre_right { position: absolute; width: 230px; top: 0px; right: 0px; height: 100%; }
```

[image: This is what it is meant to look like]

This is what it is meant to look like.

1. Problem #1 is simply a positioning problem. I want the bottom of the footer to be flush with the bottom of the page. I have tried all manner of combintions here, including bottom: 0px, height: 100% (which increases the size of the page, as if the header did not count towards the height). Switching relative and absolute positioning modes and rejigging the divs themselves. Im not understanding something about positioning though and have failed to make this work :(
2. Problem #2 is a classic, "it doesnt work in IE" kind of problem. I dont expect anybody to have a quick fix, but if you knew a good website where the problems I am having are outlined then I can fix that myself. Google is not providing me with anything useful. I might be searching for the wrong stuff :(

Comment: change your css: #footer { position: absolute; bottom:0; left:0; clear: both; height: 50px; } jsfiddle update: https://jsfiddle.net/d6nxx17y/2/

Comment: Thanks - but that kind of squished it into the left hand corner. Taking left: 0 out it aligns it correctly to the container, but then because its absolute it doesn't resize with the container.